# Bash: Sort text file by bytewise case sensitive sort command or using python sort command

Tags: python, linux, bash, sorting, case

Text File
**using sort -s**
(case sensitive)

```
Act
Bad
Bag
Card
East
about
across
back
ball
camera
canvas
danger
dark
early
edge
```

**using sort -f** (Not case sensitive)

```
about
across
Act
back
Bad
Bag
ball
camera
canvas
Card
danger
dark
early
East
edge
```

The words starting with an uppercase are sorted alphabetically between the lowercase words.

What I want is that the words in uppercase are at the start of each next letter (upercase alphabetically sorted):
**Expected output**:

```
Act
about
across
Bad
Bag
back
ball
Card
camera
canvas
danger
dark
East
early
edge
```

How can I realize this using bash or python sort command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command will do it:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -k 1.1f,1.1 PATH
```

where `PATH` is your file path.

Explanation:

- `sort` collation order is affected by the current locale, so `LC_ALL=C` is used to set the locale to a known value (the POSIX locale, collation order based on ASCII character code values)
- `-k 1.1f,1.1` tells `sort` to use the first character as the primary sort key in a case-insensitive manner
- Equal comparisons of the primary key will be resolved by comparing all characters again (this time, in a case-sensitive manner).

The output is exactly as requested in the question.

Comment: Actually, equal comparisons are resolved using all characters. That's how the uppercases get sorted before lowercases (under LC_ALL=C), even though the primary key is case-insensitive.

Comment: @Jeff Y: not 100% sure whether it collates the primary key based on locale or resolves equal comparisons against the whole field (i.e. including the primary key) again. Either way, the result is the same.

Comment: You can see that the primary key is not collated if you make the "subsequent characters" key explicit: `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1.1f,1.1 -k 1.2 TextFile`.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it! Here it is (in Python):

```
import string

words = [...]
newwords = sorted(words, key=lambda x: [ord(y) if y in string.lowercase else ord(y.lower()) - 0.5 for y in x])
print(newwords)
```

Output:

```
['Act', 'about', 'across', 'Bad', 'Bag', 'back', 'ball', 'Card', 'camera', 'canvas', 'danger', 'dark', 'East', 'early', 'edge']
```

Comment: Thanks Zondo. I forgot to write that my python version is 3.3. Your code doesn't seems to work in my python.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'`

Comment: @Reman Sorry for taking so long.  In Python3, you should use `ascii_lowercase` instead.

Comment: Zondo, It is a great solution, maybe not so easy as the bash solution but can you please tell me what you're doing? I don't understand it but it works!!

Comment: I am using a `lambda` function for the key to sort it.  The `lambda` function is given a string, and returns something that can be used to put the string in the right place.  It returns a list of the ordinal version of each letter in the string.  For example, given "string", it would give `[115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]`, but it gives the ordinal only if the letter is lowercase.  Otherwise, it gives the ordinal minus 0.5.  That way, uppercase letters are half of a letter *earlier* than the lowercase letters.  It's enough to make `B` earlier than `b`, but not enough to make it earlier than `a`.

Comment: wow, genial solution :) With this solution you can adapt almost every sort method and putting `reversed()` around reverse the sorting. Very nice.

Comment: `sorted(r, key=lambda x: [ord(y) if y in string.ascii_lowercase else ord(y.lower()) - 30 for y in x])` (-30 means all Uppercase words to the top isn't it?)

Comment: Yeah, that'll work.  Sorry for the delay.  It's my sister's birthday.

Comment: You don't really need that, though.  You can just use `sorted(r)`, and it will sort it like that by default.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm trying also the case insensitive sort command in python: `sorted(r, key=lambda s: s.lower())` but if there are two of the same words but one uppercase and one lower it puts the lowercase before the uppercase. `['act', 'about', 'About', 'bag', 'Bag']`. I want this output `['act', 'About', 'about', 'Bag', 'bag']`. Is there a way using you solution to obtain that?

Comment: Okay, I came up with a solution: `sorted(r, key=lambda x: [ord(y.lower()) for y in x[:-1]] + [ord(x[-1].lower()) + ((x[-1] in string.ascii_uppercase) / 2)])`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: `sorted(r, key=lambda x: [ord(y.lower()) for y in x[:-1]] + [ord(x[-1].lower()) + ((x[-1] in string.ascii_uppercase) / 2)])` -->
['about', 'About', 'act', 'bag', 'Bag']` But no problem I don't want to ask you more things on your sister's birthday :)

Comment: I got it.  You need to change `x[-1] in string.ascii_uppercase` to `x[0] in string.ascii_uppercase`.  My sister is in a conversation :)

Comment: Poor sister ;) Tnx for your answer. It still doesn't seem to work on my system. --> `['act', 'about', 'About', 'bag', 'Bag']`

Comment: Poor you ;) One character needs to be changed: a plus sign needs to change to minus.  Here is what it looks like: `sorted(r, key=lambda x: [ord(y.lower()) for y in x[:-1]] + [ord(x[-1].lower()) - ((x[0] in string.ascii_uppercase) / 2)]) `.  For me, this comes out with `['About', 'about', 'act', 'Bag', 'bag']`

Comment: I came up with a better one.  This one will still work even if there are uppercase letters in the middle of the word: `sorted(r, key=lambda s: [(ord(c.lower()) + ((not c.isupper()) / 2.)) for c in s])`.  You also don't need to import `string`.

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you Zondo.

Comment: It was a pleasure.  I love a challenge!